# Select column modification

Tags: sql

Say we have this value in a column

```
<color="blue" size="5"><color="red">
```

How do I replace the "red" with blue using a SQL statement?

(the value dynamic so using regular REPLACE won't do)

I'm really puzzled by how to solve it.

Comment: If it's not 'red', but 'green' why wouldn't `REPLACE(col_name, 'green', 'blue')` work? What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to change the substring where RED is now no matter what the value is. (pretend you didn't know that the second 'color' was red)

Comment: You don't say what version of Oracle you're using. It matters because if [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) is available, it would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Basically you want to replace any string like `color="…"` to `color="blue"`? In that case you'd probably need to use regular expressions of some sort. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Oracle to provide a working answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. I'm using 11g. I'm looking at the doc for REGEXP_REPLACE now and wondering if it's a solution

Comment: Do you want to only change the second `<color>` element? Or are you looking to find any `color` element at all and replace the value in it?

Comment: Yes I only want to change the value of the SECOND color element

Comment: @ob1quixote `regexp_replace` seems to replace SPECIFIED strings, strings you know the value of. Am I approaching it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) uses regular expressions to allow you to specify a *pattern* you wish you replace in a given string. Since your two `color` tags differ in structure, you can take advantage of this to specify a pattern which matches the second instance but not the first [like so (SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d8b4/11)

```
SELECT your_column,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '(.*)<color=".+">', '\1<color="blue">') AS "your_column_fixed"
  FROM your_table
;
```

This will take an input of the form `<color="blue" size="5"><color="???">` and transform it to one with the second tag replaced with `<color="blue">`. The [`.` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix001.htm#i690819) in regular expressions matches any non-null character. The `+` modifier means to match one or more occurrences of `.`. Surrounding an operator with parentheses means that the value matched will be available in the replace argument as `\n` where *n* is the corresponding position in the pattern.

Comment: This is great. I'm confused about one thing...I make the code as such: `(.*)color=".+"', '\1color="green"'`(removed the `<`) but only the second instance of color is updated- why is the first one not since now they both match?

Comment: Your pattern matches zero-or-more characters next to `color="` which changes what gets matched. Regex will default to "greedy" matches. To replace both instances of `color=".+"` you'd want a pattern with the ["lazy" modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) like `REGEXP_REPLACE("color_tags", 'color=".+?"', 'color="pink"')`

Do keep in mind: ["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I would play around with [substrings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [patindex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).

```
DECLARE @COLOR varchar(20),
@YOUR_VALUE varchar(100) 

SET @YOUR_VALUE = SUBSTRING(@YOUR_VALUE, 8, LEN(@YOUR_VALUE))
SET @COLOR = SUBSTRING(@YOUR_VALUE, 0, PATINDEX('%"%', @YOUR_VALUE))
```

The above removes 'color=" which will always be length 8, then finds the index of the next '"', then sets @COLOR to a substring up to that index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force expression:

```
select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '><color="'))||'<color="blue">'
```

It finds the first occurrence of `'><color='` and replaces the string from that point on with `'<color="blue">'`.